# How to recover a $K$-algebra from endomorphism algebra of forgetful functor?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, category-theory, modules

I'm trying to work out how a finite-dimensional $K$-algebra $B$ can be recovered from the algebra of endomorphisms of the forgetful functor $\omega$ from the category of finitely generated left $B$-modules into the category of vector spaces over $K$. This is Exercise 6.2 in Szamuely's *Galois Groups and Fundamental Groups*, and is a warm-up to Tannakian reconstruction ideas.

The $K$-vector space $\text{End}(\omega) = \left\{\text{natural transformations }\omega\to\omega\right\}$ can be made into a $K$-algebra by defining the product of two natural transformations to be their composition. However, with this definition it is not clear to me that $\text{End}(\omega)$ will be commutative, and since the eventual goal is to show an isomorphism of $K$-algebras $B\cong \text{End}(\omega)$ I may have picked the wrong product here (unless $B$ itself is not assumed commutative either).

Anyway, one can construct an injective map of $K$-algebras

$$\Phi: B\to\text{End}(\omega), \quad b\mapsto \Phi^b, \quad \Phi^b_M(m) = b \cdot m$$

where $M$ is any (finitely generated) $B$-module (i.e. $\Phi^b$ is the natural transformation whose component at $M$ is multiplication by $b\in B$ on the underlying $K$-vector space $\omega(M)$).

I am struggling to show that this map has an inverse. I would like to do something like the following: for an element $\phi\in \text{End}(\omega)$, let $b_\phi = \phi_B (1)\in B$ be the image of the multiplicative identity of $B$ under the $B$-component of $\phi$. Then I would like to show that $\Phi^{b_\phi} = \phi$ i.e. for all $B$-modules $M$ and $m\in M$,

$$\phi_B (1)\cdot m = \phi_M (m).$$

or alternatively to show that the association $\phi\mapsto \phi_B (1)$ is injective. However I am not sure how to do this (or even if this is true!) because the maps $\phi_M$ are only a priori **linear maps of vector spaces over $K$**. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Now think Yoneda.

Comment: @KevinCarlson thanks for this hint. I've thought about the Yoneda lemma though, and I guess you mean to show the two elements $\phi_B(1) m$ and $\phi_M(m)\in\omega(M)$ are equal I need to show they induce the same natural transformation $h^M \to \omega$. But this still seems tricky (or I am being a bit slow today). Could you elaborate?

Comment: The forgetful functor is represented by $B$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan somehow I managed to forget all about this. Thank you!